# URI segment to associative array in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, associative-array

I have following url:

```
www.example.com/index.php/search/search_data/Doctor:a/Gender:Male/Language:Urdu/
```

and I want to convert it to associative array like

```
$data=array(
       'Doctor'=> 'a',
       'Gender'=> 'Male',
       'Language'=> 'Urdu'
);
```

I have tried to do this using codeIgniter's URI class function

```
$this->uri->uri_to_assoc(n)
```

but as it accepts the data to be separated via **'/'** but I am having data with **':'** as separator.

please help me.

Comment: The uri_to_assoc() function parses the uri segment values, you want to split the values. Why don't you write a customer helper function to do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an easier way to do this, rather than to do it manually.

First, retrieve the total segments, loop through, see if it contains ":", then add it into the array.

```
$segments = $this->uri->segment_array();

$search_array = array();

foreach($segments as $segment) {
    if (strpos($segment, ":") !== FALSE) {
       $e_array = explode(":", $segment);
       $search_array[$e_array[0]] = $e_array[1];
    }
}
```

Running that snippet somewhere will give you desirable results, **$search_array** will be an associative array with key => value.

Answer (score 0):

You could hack the URI.php file. Change lines 431 - 439 to;

```
if (strpos($seg, ":") !== FALSE) {
    list($parameter, $value) = explode(':', $seg);
    if ($i % 2) {
        $retval[$parameter] = $value;
    } else {
        $retval[$parameter] = $value;
        $lastval = $seg;
    }
} else {
    if ($i % 2) {
        $retval[$lastval] = $seg;
    } else {
        $retval[$seg] = FALSE;
        $lastval = $seg;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice suggestion, but i would note for it since it will break the code once you update CI/ or you have to do it again everytime you update CI